# CSS disappears locally after precompiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Now this may be a stupid question for those who are familiarized with the front end stuff when using Rails, but I'm not one of them.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this as a bad practice: I precompile the assets locally before loading my local server to see the changes with `rake assets:precompile`. Shouldn't I be doing that?

My actual problem though is, this last time I precompiled assets my whole CSS stylesheet seemed to disappear from the view, the page I was making the layout for looks like a raw HTML page now.

Tried to `rake assets:clean` already (not sure if this should help at all anyway).

Forgive my inexperience, I'm new to the front end stuff.

Comment: Use Developer Tools or Firebug to see if the CSS file is being loaded. Btw, why are you precompiling them? Are you running the server in production mode? If not, and you're running on development, you don't have to precompile them, go ahead and remove them from public/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in development mode, you don't have to precompile them. So remove them from public/ and just run your server.

Comment: I deleted all the public folder and page is still loading the same way. I don't know why the stylesheets are not loading properly since they did before I precompiled assets the last time. Any thoughts?